# Add new phone number to contact in AddressBook programmatically (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts, phone-number, addressbook

I dont want to create a new contact in my AddressBook, i just want add a new phone number to existing contact.

Example:

Contact XYZ have

1. mobile: 12435656
2. iPhone: 2413545
3. Home: 9849528

I want to add other like this:

Contact XYZ have

1. mobile: 12435656
2. iPhone: 2413545
3. Home: 9849528
4. **NEW PHONE: 0901903910**

How can I make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1) that you can read. What you are looking for is in the [properties section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW9). read about single-value and multi value properties, its probably what you need.

Comment: Thanks!! 
now it's working!



`ABMultiValueRef Phones = ABRecordCopyValue(recordID, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
ABMutableMultiValueRef Phone = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(Phones);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(Phone,updatedPhone, kABOtherLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(recordID, kABPersonPhoneProperty, Phone,nil);    ABAddressBookSave(_myAddressBook, nil);
CFRelease(Phone);`

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow Apple's [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Hope that helps